# How to write a jenkins pipeline script to run the selenium test suite

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I am setting up a jenkins pipeline to run my selenium test suite. I want to know how to write the pipeline script which can checkout my project and run my regression test suite.

My project consists only of Selenium test suites which are run across an application URL.
Application URL is provided through application.properties

My Regression test suite consists of all test suites. I want to set up a jenkins pipeline , when run the job, I want to execute all the tests.

I want to know the different stages in pipeline and how to write it.
AuthenticationTest.java and BiographicInfoTest.java contatins actual Tests written using TestNg and selenium.

I was following this [link](https://testrig.medium.com/running-selenium-tests-in-jenkins-pipelines-for-continuous-integration-3b1e7f6362a7), but didn't know where to start.

```
application.properties
app_url =http://myservername:8090/MyProject/

regression-test.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Regression Test Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="myproject.selenium.utils.CustomisedReports" />
    </listeners>
    
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="./checkUserAuthentication.xml"></suite-file>
        <suite-file path="./checkUserBiographicInformation.xml"></suite-file>
    </suite-files>  
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

checkUserAuthentication.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="User Authentication"> 
  <test name="User Authentication">
    <classes>    
      <class name="myproject.selenium.user.authentication.AuthenticationTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->


checkUserBiographicInformation.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="User Biographic Information"> 
  <test name="User Biographic Information">
    <classes>    
      <class name="myproject.selenium.user.authentication.BiographicInfoTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your gradle tests in pipeline or docker(file)

```
stage('tests'){
  steps{
    sh 'gradle test --tests my-test-cases.*'
  }
}
```

For success execution your tests must be configured correctly(dependencies, urls, addresses, properties etc)

For build env you can use [gradle tools plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gradle/) or [docker gradle image](https://hub.docker.com/_/gradle/)